# How can I change the value of a setter with input? JAVA

Tags: java

Hi so the problem I have is I cant change the value of this setter using an integer (input from scanner) for some reason I dont understand. Im using an array aswell and a mainclass.

This exact coding worked when I used a string as the input. But when I try to do it with an int (which i have to in this case cause Im working with hours) it wont work... Is there a solution to this? or another way to code it.

Comment: "The method setEmployeeHours() in the type Employee is not applicable for the arguments (int)" <- That means the method `setEmployeeHours` you are trying to call does not take a single int as an argument. By the looks of it it doesn't take any argument at all which makes little sense for a setter. Did you write that method yourself and can maybe add it to the code?

Comment: yes ill try and add it

Comment: Do u have any POJO class for setter if not then try to create POJO so that you can add getter and setter over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Getter and Setter method of employee class for setting employee hours should look like this.

```
public void setEmployeeHours(int hour){
this.hours=hour;
}

public int getEmployeeHours(){
return hours;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You just saved me 100 hours id be sitting trying to solve this XD